# indexOf returning "-1" when it should return "4"

Tags: javascript, indexof

```
var odd = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9];

function testFunction() {
    numbers = document.getElementById("inputfield").value;

    alert(odd.indexOf(numbers[0]));
}
```

It alerts "-1" for some reason, even if I split "number" first to turn it into an array.

I even tried `index=number[0];` and then `alert(odd.indexOf(index));` but it's still not working

Here is a demo http://jsfiddle.net/y0ruba/NUzAD/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `parseInt`

`numbers[0]` will return a string value. since `odd` is array of numbers, 
it cannot find its index. So, convert `numbers[0]` to an integer using `parseInt`

**[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NUzAD/4/)**

```
numbers = document.getElementById("inputfield").value;
var x = parseInt(numbers[0]);
alert(odd.indexOf(x));
```

Answer (score 3):

That's because `number[0]` is `undefined`.

```
var number = 1;
var array = [ "a", "b" ]
number[0]; // undefined
array.indexOf(undefined); // -1
```

---

If you change the `alert` line to:

```
alert(odd.indexOf(parseInt(("" + numbers)[0], 10)));
```

it should work. First cast `numbers` to a string, then get the `0`th digit, then cast it back to a number. In JSFiddle this gives me `4`

Comment: its not undefined, if i alert number[0] i get 9

Comment: I see what you're trying to do. Cast the number to a first. `var number = "1"; number[0]; // 1` or use `substr`

Comment: a wrong answer with 3 upvotes. Most SO users don't even care what they are seeing

Comment: I see where the confusion is coming from. When you do `input.value` you always get a `string`. When you do `var num = 5` you get a `number`. Your JSFiddle code doesn't match the code your posted in your question.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen this doesnt work either http://jsfiddle.net/y0ruba/NUzAD/11/ thats why im confused

Comment: That's your original code, I thought we agreed it doesn't work. See my updated answer.

Comment: i thought you could treat numbers as arrays like you can with strings, my bad, your answer is right but i asked the wrong question

Answer (score 2):

`number[0]` is a `string`. You must cast it before using `indexOf` so it can match the number.

```
var odd = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9];
alert(odd.indexOf(+numbers[0]));
```

[**Working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/NUzAD/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Numbers don't have indices. The best you can do is `parseInt((99936).toString()[0])`, which would be `9` in your case.